# How to delete only one row if several found?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that looks like this.

```
CREATE TABLE tshirt
(
  id serial,
  sku character varying(255) NOT NULL
);
```

I want to delete only one row with my wanted sku, but `DELETE FROM tshirt WHERE sku='%s';`
deletes all entries with that sku. How can I do this ?

Comment: Eh? Delete by id. If you don't know it, then how can you know which one needs to be deleted.

Comment: How do you know which sky you want to keep

Comment: It doesnt matter which row gets deleted. If I there are two matching rows I just need to delete one, doesn't matter which one.

Comment: What if there are 3, or 6789. Perhaps it would be better to put a unique constraint on SKU. Experience suggests that this is going to matter at some point in the future, and at that point you are going to be calling yourself names, which won't include genius, clever, perspicacious etc

Comment: @TonyHopkinson it won't grow that much, I believe that 50rows is going to be the maximum for this table.

Comment: Not only useful in case of a previous table definition, but also a way to prevent a disaster when ppl gets distracted just in time to write a wrong WHERE clause

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not the best way but, you could do this:

```
DELETE FROM tshirt
WHERE id IN (
   SELECT id FROM
   tshirt WHERE sku='%s' LIMIT 1
)
```

Comment: Not the best way? I nominate you for the understatement of the year award. Which one do you think this would delete, or is that irrelevant?

Comment: according to his question he doesn't really cares which record gets deleted, he needs to delete only one

Comment: This _is_ the best way to achieve what he wants - delete one row, doesn't matter which. A simple query that does the job. Of course, its sanity is still under question.

Comment: Btw, you may want to use `ctid` or `oid` if there's no unique key `id`.

Comment: Well yeah but the best way to shoot yourself in the foot, is to press the gun against it and pull the trigger. Doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Comment: This is wrong, I have tried this query and it deleted 2 rows. Here is what I 've tried delete from public.test where "Id" IN (select "Id" from public.test where "Id"=1 LIMIT 1)

Answer (score 9):

This SQL Server DELETE TOP example would delete the first record from the employees table where the last_name is 'Anderson'. If there are other records in the employees table that have a last_name of 'Anderson', they will not be deleted by the DELETE TOP statement.

```
DELETE TOP(1)
FROM employees
WHERE last_name = 'Anderson';
```

Answer (score 3):

This deletes *all but one* (which makes more sense to me than deleting *exactly* one)

```
DELETE FROM tshirt del
WHERE del.sku = '%s'; 
AND EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM tshirt ex
    WHERE ex.shu = del.shu  -- same shirt
    and ex.id < del.id      -- different number
    );
```

BTW: to avoid this kind of problem in the future, you should add a few constraints to the table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE tshirt
(
        -- surrogate key
  id serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        -- natural key
  , sku character varying(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE
);
```

Answer (score 3):

You could leverage the implicit ctid column found in every table.

```
# create temporary table foo ( x integer );
CREATE TABLE
Time: 4.267 ms
# insert into foo values (1),(2),(3);
INSERT 0 3
Time: 0.549 ms
# delete from foo where ctid = (select ctid from foo limit 1) returning *;
 x
---
 1
(1 row)

DELETE 1
Time: 0.737 ms
# select * from foo;
 x
---
 2
 3
(2 rows)
```

Time: 0.267 ms

Answer (score 2):

tell the database **which** row you like to delete by adding another constraint like

DELETE FROM tshirt WHERE sku='sku_you_like_to_match' and serial = '555' ;